# LARAVEL: One-to-one relationship on a pivot table?

Tags: laravel

I can't think of how to handle this in Eloquent. I have a many-to-many relationship that needs a one-to-one relationship assigned to it.

Here is the basic database structure I designed in its simplest form:

```
ACCOUNTS: id

AGENTS: id

FEES: id

ACCOUNT_AGENT: account_id, agent_id, fee_id
```

Each Account belongsToMany Agents.

Each Agent belongsToMany Accounts.

Each "Account_Agent" (the many-to-many pivot table) belongsTo Fee.

How do I define that third relationship in an Eloquent model?

I want to be able to access the "account_agent" fee like this (or similar):

```
$account = Account::first();

foreach ($account->agents as $agent) {
  echo $agent->fee;
}
```

Thanks, hopefully my question is clear.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30649810/three-way-many-to-many-relationship-in-laravel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Scroll down to **Defining Custom Intermediate Table Models**

Basically what you have to do is to define a class like this:

```
class AccountAgent extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot
{
    /**
     * Many:1 relationship with Fee model
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function fee()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Fee::class);
    }
}
```

Then you define your many:many relationship in your Account class like this:

```
/**
 * The agents that belong to the account.
 */
public function agents()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Agent::class)->using(AccountAgent::class);
}
```

Then in your code, instead of this:

```
foreach ($account->agents as $agent) {
  echo $agent->fee;
}
```

... do this:

```
foreach ($account->agents as $agent) {
  /** @var Fee $fee_object */
  $fee_object = $agent->pivot->fee;
}
```

In that loop $fee_object is of class Fee (the model class that covers the fees table) so you could `echo $fee_object->fee_amount` or whatever other columns you need to use.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking creating a model for the pivot table was the way to go but I just didn't know exactly how it was done :)

Comment: You're welcome. I will say that I had to restrain myself from pointing out that if you have a class called "Fee" then you also need more classes called "Fie", "Foe" and "Fum". :)