# Laravel more than two Many-to-Many Relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

following up on this thread 
[Three-way many-to-many relationship in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30649810/three-way-many-to-many-relationship-in-laravel)

I am trying to reproduce this example because I find this is a neat approach to implement a three way many-to-many relation via Eloquent.

But I am getting an error when I try to retrieve anything :

```
$user->relations()->where('student_id', $student)->first()->plan();
```

Tinker tells me that there should be a pivot table relation_user. 
If this is the case the solution won't be "neat" as appealing anymore.
There have to be something I am missing, this thread doesn't show the migrations, is there a way to reproduce what *Carlos Herrera Plata* is saying on this thread ?

**EDIT**:

This is the example on the link the way I implemented it

```
class Dftstudent extends Model
{
    function relations() {
        return $this->hasMany(Dftrelation::class);
    }
}
class Dftplan extends Model
{
    function relations() {
        return $this->hasMany(Dftrelation::class);
    }
}
class Dftuser extends Model
{
    function relations() {
        return $this->hasMany(Dftrelation::class);
    }
}
```

while in the relation model

```
class Dftrelation extends Model
{
    function student() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Dftstudent::class);
    }

    function user() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Dftuser::class);
    }

    function plan() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Dftplan::class);
    }
 //
}
```

Migration in the relation table :

```
 Schema::create('dftrelations', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('student_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('plan_id')->unsigned();
    $table->timestamps();
  });
  Schema::table('dftrelations', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('dftusers');
    $table->foreign('student_id')->references('id')->on('dftstudents');
    $table->foreign('plan_id')->references('id')->on('dftplans');
  });
```

while the other models Dftstudent, Dftplan, Dftuser just contains id and name.

I filled them with the following data:

```
INSERT INTO dftusers (name) VALUES ("admin1"), ("admin2");
INSERT INTO dftstudents (name) VALUES ("Pete"), ("Sam");
INSERT INTO dftplans (name) VALUES ("plan A"), ("plan B");
INSERT INTO dftrelations (user_id, student_id, plan_id) VALUES (1,1,1), (2,2,2);
```

Comment: In any many to many relationship you need a pivot table. I don't understand how you expect to have many to many without one

Comment: The point is that the relation table model is actually structured in a way to make up for the pivot table. The difference is that it's pivoting three models rather than only two and that's not the standard with eloquent.

Comment: Can you share your relevant models? I'd expect you can use the 3-way pivot as a 2-way pivot with extra columns (e.g. using `withPivot("extra")` ) provided you let eloquent know

Comment: It's the same example on the link ... Anyway I will be posting it.

Comment: I used withPivot before in some context, it seems sound in here may be, I'll try it