# How to Query Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel. I have a problem on laravel relationship. Can you guys help me?

I have four tables:
1. Users
2. Teams
3. Games
4. Picks

**Picks** is my intermediate table model
1. `id`
2. `user_id`
3. `team_id`
4. `game_id`

**User class**

```php
class User extends Model
{
  public function picks()
  {
     return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Pick');
  }
}
```

**Team class**

```php
class Team extends Model
{
  public function picks()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Pick');
  }
}
```

**Game class**

```php
class Game extends Model
{
   public function picks()
   {
     return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Pick');
   }
}
```

```php
class Pick extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User');
    }

    public function teams()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Team');
    }

    public function schedules()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Schedule');
    }
}
```

How can I convert this query to eloquent?

```sql
"SELECT * FROM `games` AS g LEFT JOIN `picks` as p ON p.game_id = g.id LEFT JOIN `users` as u ON u.id = p.user_id WHERE u.id = 1;"
```

I want to get games through the picks via user id.

Comment: Did you make the Models? Like how far did you get?

Comment: @NielsLucas yup I already created the Models. Edited my posts, sorry.

Comment: @LLJ97 yeah but I cannot find any answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you almost got it right tho.

Your User model relation should match the class what is trying to reach, the table between al handled in the background.

```
    class User extends Model
{
  public function games()
  {
     return $this->belongsToMany(Games::class, 'picks'); <-- i prefer this over string
  }
}
```

then somewhere in your controller you can just do this

```
$user = User::find(1);
$games = $user->games; <-- should work but if not
$games = $user->games()->get() <-- has to do with lazy loading.
```

EDIT: i changed the table to picks at the relationship

Comment: Tried it but still not working :( but thanks for the help tho.

Comment: yeah i got an error: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'schedules.picks' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `schedules` where `schedules`.`picks` = 1 and `schedules`.`picks` is not null)

Comment: so thats an error with another table not with the relationship you al trying right now. Pick is more like a pivot table, and should not be considered used as a Model.

Comment: Do you still refer your relation to the Pick table?

Comment: Ok i see. But laravel don't support 3 way many to many relationship. So I've search it and got the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30649810/three-way-many-to-many-relationship-in-laravel.

Comment: this is not a 3 way tho. You just try to get the games from a user right? 'Pick' here is just a table that connects them. just belongsToMany()

Comment: Hi Niel. Thanks fo the help. What I did was I removed all the codes on the Models and define the relationship again and now its working. Idk why its not working yesterday lol. Thank you!

Comment: No problem mate, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to jump over the table.
Check the documentation:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: he is just trying to get the games where user with id = 1 ? so just a many to many. If correctly set
```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->getGames() <-- many to many
```

Comment: Although the link can be helpful (if you're working with relationships and don't want to do the query explicit) you should put the essential information of the link in the answer itself. If the link dies this answer isn't helpful anymore

Comment: Yeah already tried hasManyHrough but my games table don't have a foreign key for picks.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Pick` model is wrong. All the relationships should be `BelongsTo()` instead of `BelongsToMany()` since a Pick belongs to only one User one Team and one Schedule.

**Pick Model**

```php
class Pick extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }

    public function team()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Team');
    }

    public function schedule()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Schedule');
    }
}
```

Now, to get Games for particular Pick Which belongs to a Particular User.

**Controller Function**

```php
$userId = '1';

$games = Game::whereHas('picks', function($query) use ($userId) {
    // Here you have a query for picks table.
    $query->where('user_id', $userId);
})
->get();
```